# Cannot use "uniform_int_distribution" in Mingw-w64, but "exponential_distribution" works

Tags: c++, c++11, random, g++, mingw-w64

For some reason, I cannot use `uniform_int_distribution` (from C++ TR1 header `<tr1/random>`) in Mingw-w64 G++, even though `exponential_distribution` works. The following is the relevant code:

```c++
#include <tr1/random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    tr1::random_device rd;
    tr1::exponential_distribution<int> exprng(1);
    tr1::uniform_int_distribution<> unirng(5, 500);
    tr1::mt19937 rnd_gen(rd());
    // ...
}
```

When I try to compile it, I get this:

```
> g++ -o foo.exe -std=c++11 foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:8:5: error: 'uniform_int_distribution' is not a member of 'std::tr1'
     tr1::uniform_int_distribution<> unirng(5, 500)
     ^
foo.cpp:8:35: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
     tr1::uniform_int_distribution<> unirng(5, 500);
                                   ^
foo.cpp:8:50: error: 'unirng' was not declared in this scope
     tr1::uniform_int_distribution<> unirng(5, 500);
                                                  ^
```

I'm running the latest version of the compiler, 4.9.2. I've already tried removing `using namespace std` and changing the namespace prefix to `std::tr1` and `std`. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it called just `uniform_int` in TR1? For `uniform_int_distribution`, include `<random>` from the C++11 Standard Library, not TR1.

Comment: Great, that worked. Composing a self-answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I got the C++ TR1 and C++11 headers mixed up.

I was using C++ TR1 headers as a result of my misreading the GCC documentation, but it turns out `uniform_int_distribution` is part of C++11. C++11 and C++ TR1 aren't exactly source-compatible and minor adjustments are needed.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    random_device rd;
    exponential_distribution<> exprng(1);
    uniform_int_distribution<> unirng(5, 500);
    mt19937 rnd_gen(rd());
    // ...
}
```

(I'll cast the `exponential_distribution` output later in the program—the compiler told me that the template argument *must* be a floating-point type.)